# PIVPN with Wireguards - Hide IP

Tags: pi-2, vpn, raspberry-pi-desktop

i have a question: i installed PIVPN with Wireguard protocol. From my mobile phone, my endpoint is the my ip public and with a specific port, I reach out my VPN. Perfect! My data are encrypted between my mobile phone and VPN but not between my VPN and Internet. Is there a way to hide my public ip ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what does your public IP have to do with encryption? if you want to hide your public IP (of the raspberry pi) then don't use your raspberry pi as the VPN endpoint

Comment: Ok! The command " iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x"can hide my public IP? Thanks

I would like to study this process, nothing else

Comment: You can't hide the IP of the pi, since that's the endpoint of the VPN through which you are making requests - if you use one of those advertised commercial VPN's, your public IP is hidden because the request looks like it comes from that  commercial VPN's IP address - I think you've misunderstood VPN's - their primary function has nothing to do with hiding your IP address

Comment: Ok so there isn't  a way to obtain anonymous between VPN and internet with PIVPN

Comment: the anonymity comes from having a VPN server whose IP address is not yours ... the "hide your IP" aspect of VPN's is not the primary purpose of VPN's anyway - it's how commercial VPN's market themselves, and the only way to "hide your IP" is to use one of those commercial VPN's - because their servers aren't in your house

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you please make your comments an answer? I would upvote it.

Comment: For hiding your connection from the RasPi to the internet you may consider to connect to the **Tor** network.